# Google Sheets function IMPORTXML not returning results for XML despite well formed selector?

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to select elements from the following XML

http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/realtime.asmx/getStationDataByCodeXML?StationCode=mhide

The XML seems well structured, using the selector `"//*"` I am able to get all the information.

But using any other selector like `"//Traincode"` gives a `"#NA"` Error.

However, using http://xpather.com/ it looks like this should work.

Any help is appreciated

My function looks like

```
=IMPORTXML("http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/realtime.asmx/getStationDataByCodeXML?StationCode=mhide", "//Traincode")
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like GS is treating default [namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) differently than xpather (or some others like it).

Change the xpath expression to

```
//*[local-name()='Traincode']
```

and the output should be:

```
E811 
D821 
E812 
E222 
P724 
P725 
E115
```